# Random draw with replacement, probability of no more than $1$ repeat

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

An urn contains $n$ different items, one is marked. Items are drawn at random from it with replacement until the marked item is drawn. What is the probability each item appears no more than once? What is the minimum $n$ for said probability to be less than 1/2?

Now, obviously the probability can be calculated as 
$$\frac{1}{n}\left[1 + \dfrac{n-1}{n} + \dfrac{n-1}{n} \cdot \dfrac{n-2}{n} + ... +\dfrac{(n-1)!}{n^{n-1}}\right]$$

and the minimum $n$ is 6 by brute force calculation. Is there any way to pretty it up?

Comment: The formula can be *prettied* up, though idk if that helps.$\;\;\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{^nP_k}{n^{k+1}}$